# How can we display text just below the picture without using display property?

Tags: html, css

Actually, I want to to display text just below the picture in a box and I don't want to use display property, which other property can I  use?

I tried grid template rows property but it's not giving desired look.

Comment: `... <img ... /> <br> <span>Hello</span> ...`

Comment: You need to show us the code you have tried so far and also a sketch of what you want the output to look like would be good. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And perhaps describing why you don't want to use the display property would be useful - because by the sounds of it your layout might be a simple grid.

Comment: By the way, for the grid layout you also need to use the display property (`display: grid`)

Answer (score 4):

You should provide an example of what you have tried, ideally a code-snippet that can be executed for us to see.

That said, what you describe sounds like what the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements could be used for:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" />
  <figcaption>This is your caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the content for the element is limited to be a styled plain text, you may use the css strategy using the pseudoelement `::after`

Consider that, as highlighted in the comment, this solution doesn't fulfill the accessibility concerns.

It's just an attempt to achieve a given result using css only but breaking some rules.

I'll leave it here to show how not to do it.

```css
.gallery{
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

#target{
  outline: solid red 4px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#target::after{
  content: attr(data-caption);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: solid 1px gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="404_1.jpg" alt="<img>" id="target" data-caption="Caption 1...">
  <img src="404_2.jpg" alt="<img>" id="target" data-caption="Caption 2...">
  <img src="404_3.jpg" alt="<img>" id="target" data-caption="Caption 3...">
  <img src="404_4.jpg" alt="<img>" id="target" data-caption="Caption 4...">
</div>
```

Comment: One of the problems with this approach might be accessibility - screen readers may not read out the CSS content.

Comment: Yes and the figcaption is way much better..I was the first to upvote that one :)